# Killing process started through a golang program

Tags: go

I have a daemon process running and that starts another process. To simulate it right now I have just put 'sleep'. If I kill the process, it remains as zombie. How to clean it properly.

```
cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "500")
err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to kill process: ", err)
}
time.Sleep(10000000 * time.Millisecond)
```

`$ ps aux | grep sleep`

37342   0.0  0.0  4276984   1040 s000  S+    5:09PM   0:00.00 grep sleep

37309   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z     5:09PM   0:00.00 (sleep)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`cmd.Wait()`](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Wait) for it to finish.  (In Unix in general, you need to **wait**(2) to avoid leaking zombies.)

`"os/exec"` doesn't have a non-blocking variant of this (there's no equivalent to **waitpid**(2)) but you can wait in a goroutine:

```
// Start the subprocess
cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "500")
err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}

// Wait for it to finish
done := make(chan struct{})
go (func () {
        cmd.Wait()
        close(done)
})()

// Set a timeout
timeout := time.NewTimer(5 * time.Second)

select {
case <-done:
        fmt.Println("process completed")
        if !timeout.Stop() {
                <-timeout.C
        }
case <-timeout.C:
        fmt.Println("deadline ran out, killing process")
        if err := cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal("failed to kill process: ", err)
        }
        <-done
}
```

Only one branch of the `select` will fire, and each does the cleanup necessary for the other one.  In the timeout case, after the process is killed, `Wait()` should return immediately, which should signal the "done" channel.